# In Fusion Tables, can a gradient be set via the Google Maps Javascript-based API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

This is my code below. For some reason, the only style that render properly are the stroke (it's white) and the opacity (set at 0.4). However, my gradient doesn't seem to load. Instead, it's all red. Why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Customizing Fusion Tables map using Fusion Tables' Javascript API</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #map-canvas {
            height: 800px;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> <!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locationColumn = "geometry";
        var tableId = "1FbzvoRkdJzXvIxMJg2mGYVz5Q1BW2-4feMolgVc"; // California Census Tracts FT
        var condition = "'Median income (dollars)'>0";

        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        function initialize() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
            var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                    select: locationColumn,
                    from: tableId,
                    where: condition
                },
                styles: [
                    {
                        polygonOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#ffffff",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.4,
                            strokeWeight: 1,

                            fillColorStyler: {
                                kind: "fusiontables#gradient",
                                columnName: "Median income (dollars)",

                                gradient: {
                                    min: 28183.65,
                                    max: 122762.9,
                                    colors: [
                                        {
                                            color:"#990000",
                                            opacity:0.4
                                        },
                                        {
                                            color:"ffd966",
                                            opacity:0.4
                                        },
                                        {
                                            color:"#274e13",
                                            opacity:0.4
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            geocoder.geocode(
                {
                    'address':'California'
                },
                function(results,status){
                    var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
                    var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);
                    gmap.fitBounds(bounds)
                }
            );

            layer.setMap(gmap);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1**

I did some more research. Unfortunately, this feature is not supported. Your code has `new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer` and there is no mention of gradients in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables). I recommend using my last solution (which works well) or the [business demographics layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics#gradients) which *does* support gradients. The same conclusion was reached here: [Gradient for Fusion Table Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791898/gradient-for-fusion-table-layer). So, to answer your question: no, you cannot create a gradient using Google Maps JavaScript-based API.

**Update 0**

I was able to accomplish the desired gradient using [Google Maps JavaScript API v3: Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers). Specifically, I found a useful example in the [Fusion Table Styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) sub-section.

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/alahup/1/edit

**Relevant Code**

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
      select: locationColumn,
      from: tableId,
      where: condition
  },
  styles: [{
      where: "'Median income (dollars)' < 35000",
      polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#2EFEF7',
          fillOpacity: 0.4
      }
  }, {
      where: "'Median income (dollars)' > 34999.99 AND 'Median income (dollars)' < 65000",
      polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#2E9AFE',
          fillOpacity: 0.4
      }
  }, {
      where: "'Median income (dollars)' > 64999.99 AND 'Median income (dollars)' < 120000",
      polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#2E2EFE',
          fillOpacity: 0.4
      }
  }, {
      where: "'Median income (dollars)' > 119999.99",
      polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: '#0B0B61',
          fillOpacity: 0.4
      }
  }]
});
```

**Result**

[image: Fusion Table Gradient Example]

---

Here's a quick solution:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: locationColumn,
                from: tableId,
                where: condition
            },
            styleId: 2 // <-- replace current style code with this
 });
```

[Gradient for Fusion Table Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791898/gradient-for-fusion-table-layer) has some more information about predefined styles. I'd look into that further.

---

**Also**, this example by Google looks to be nearly the same as what you are trying to accomplish. I'd review and use their code.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/adv_fusiontables

[image]

Comment: Hm, does that mean that I can use the Javascript-based API to make a map colored with buckets, but not a true gradient color scheme?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Fusion Tables to know but the API appears flexible enough to use or setup a gradient.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Did the Google example help?

Comment: Nah, not true the JavaScript API, but it looks like the non-Javascript-based Fusion Tables API can do this -- even though the changes are applied directly to the Fusion Table. What I'd like is to change how it looks to the user without changing the table's attributes.

Comment: Hm, it does look good, though when I say "gradient," I mean the gradient you see in Fusion Tables when you click on a map, then go to "Change map styles." One of the "fill" options is gradient-style.